# Javascript: сравнение элементов массива - первый элемент содержит второй

Tags: javascript

Есть [задача](https://learn.freecodecamp.org/javascript-algorithms-and-data-structures/basic-algorithm-scripting/mutations/)
Мое решение такое:

```js
function mutation(arr) {
  let item1 = arr[0].toLowerCase();
  let item2 = arr[1].toLowerCase();
  let result;
  for (let i=0; i<item2.length; i++) {
    result = item1.includes(item2[i]);
      if (result) {
      return true;
    } return false;
  }
}
mutation(["hello", "hey"]);
```

При передаче массива ["hello", "hey"] функция выдает результат true. Хотя все остальные тесты - все ок. С методом .indexOf() решение, которое предоставили авторы курса:

```js
function mutation(arr) {
  var test = arr[1].toLowerCase();
  var target = arr[0].toLowerCase();
  for (var i=0;i<test.length;i++) {
    if (target.indexOf(test[i]) < 0)
      return false;
  }
  return true;
 }
```

В чем принципиальная разница в моем решении и авторским? Почему мое пасует в одном из тестов?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) работает аналогично `!(indexOf() < 0)`, поэтому если заменить вызовы в одном из примеров можно сравнить полученный код:

```
// не работает
function mutation(arr) {
  let item1 = arr[0].toLowerCase();
  let item2 = arr[1].toLowerCase();
  let result;
  for (let i=0; i<item2.length; i++) {
    result = item1.includes(item2[i]);
      if (result) {
      return true;
    } 
    return false;
  }
}

// работает
function mutation(arr) {
  var test = arr[1].toLowerCase();
  var target = arr[0].toLowerCase();
  for (var i=0;i<test.length;i++) {
    if (!target.includes(test[i]))
      return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

Можно отметить, что за исключением имен переменных, в коде присутствует важное отличие: в рабочем коде один из `return` находится **вне** цикла, в то время как в нерабочем - оба *внутри*.

Comment: includes и indexOf() < 0 отдаст разный результат

Comment: @WanSpi, логично :-) поправил

Comment: @WanSpi - большое спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Вы проверяете только первый элемент:

```
function mutation(arr) {
  let item1 = arr[0].toLowerCase();
  let item2 = arr[1].toLowerCase();
  let result;
  for (let i=0; i<item2.length; i++) {
    result = item1.includes(item2[i]);
      if (result) {
      return true;
    } return false; //получили резалт, и сразу же вернули true или фалсе
  }
  //я думаю суда надо return false перенести
}
mutation(["hello", "hey"]);
```

Comment: большое спасибо, но к сожалению данное решение проходит тест только с положительным исходом, то есть true. False функция не возвращает

Comment: @DzmitryLapeto Все верно, так как вы сравниваете слово "hello", с буквами "h", "e", "y"

Comment: @WanSpi поменял условие в операторе if и заработало! Не могли бы вы еще объяснить в чем принципиальная разница между: "возвращать true если true, иначе false" и наоборот?

Comment: @DzmitryLapeto можете показать как у Вас сейчас выглядит код?

Comment: @WanSpi проще говоря объясните в чем разница между function mutation(arr) {
  let item1 = arr[0].toLowerCase();
  let item2 = arr[1].toLowerCase();
  let result;
  for (let i=0; i<item2.length; i++) {
    result = item1.includes(item2[i]);
      if (result) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
} и function mutation(arr) {
  let item1 = arr[0].toLowerCase();
  let item2 = arr[1].toLowerCase();
  let result;
  for (let i=0; i<item2.length; i++) {
    result = item1.includes(item2[i]);
      if (result==false) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}

Comment: @DzmitryLapeto первый пример вернет true если найдет хоть один элемент, если же не найдет, то вернет false, второй же пример, вернет true только в том случае, если все элементы будут в массиве, к примеру для первого случая mutation(["hello", "hey"]) true или mutation(["world", "hey"]) false, для второго же примера  mutation(["hello", "hello"]) true или mutation(["hello", "hey"]) false или mutation(["hello", "olleh"]) true или mutation(["hello", "h"]) true

Comment: @WanSpi понял, благодарю!